# Pre-processing AngularJS output

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to add a pre-processing step to AngularJS before it updates any HTML. For the sake of simplicity, let's have it bold all instances of `hello`.

That is, if we let `$scope.text = "hello world!"`, we want somehow to have

```
{{ text }}
```

evaluate during the `$digest` cycle into

```
<b>hello</b> world!
```

If `$scope.text` is changed, this would of course update as appropriate.

How would this be done? Preferably, it would be a directive, so that any expressions inside a `<div boldhello></div>` would be processed.

Comment: This case seems simple enough that a filter would probably work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[datasage's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34475691/pre-processing-angularjs-output#comment56693091_34475691) is spot on - this is a great place for a filter. Here's a basic filter adapted from [the documentation examples](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter) that replaces any instance of `hello` with one surrounded by bold tags:

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('myFilterApp', [])
    .filter('boldHello', function($sce) {
      return function(input) {
        input = input || '';
        var out = input.replace(/hello/gi, function(text) {
          return '<b>' + text + '</b>';
        });
        return out;
      };
    })
    .controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.greeting = 'Oh, hello, my friend.';
    }]);
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myFilterApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    <input ng-model="greeting" type="text"><br>
    No filter: {{greeting}}<br>
    Bold: {{greeting | boldHello}}<br>
  </div>
</body>
```

But alas, the tags are printed in the output! That's because Angular keeps you safe from accidental HTML injection (which might contain `script` tags), so we need to mark this explicitly safe. You mark it safe with `trustAsHtml`, and we need to put the result into your template using the `ng-bind-html` directive.

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('myFilterApp', [])
    .filter('boldHello', function($sce) {
      return function(input) {
        input = input || '';
        var out = input.replace(/hello/gi, function(text) {
          return '<b>' + text + '</b>';
        });
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(out);
      };
    })
    .controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.greeting = 'Oh, hello, my friend.';
    }]);
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myFilterApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    <input ng-model="greeting" type="text"><br>
    No filter: {{greeting}}<br>
    Bold: <span ng-bind-html="greeting | boldHello"></span><br>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Huh, filters are pretty cool. One thing - this is for a chat application, so if the user enters arbitrary HTML and this find-replace algorithm does its work, it ends up not sanitizing the HTML. How do you prevent this?

Comment: The simplest thing is to immediately remove any `<tags>` from the user's input, or convert `<`/`>` to `&lt;`/`&gt;`. If you want them able to type some tags, you'll need a smarter filter, or some other solution.